# Как поменять название окна в Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer

Хочу поменять название окна в *Qt Designer*, но никак не могу найти как это сделать, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Михаил, покажите код, который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите/ покажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Дело не в коде. В самом Qt designer у меня есть окно, в его имени написано "Untitled", а я хочу поставить своё, но не могу найти где можно отредактировать

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен что правильно понимаю то, что вы хотите сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Михаил что не так?